# trying to find my ssl certificate I created on AWS Certificates

Tags: amazon-web-services, https, certificate, pem

I setup my ec2 instance and got https working for a bit only to realize I need tls 1.2 on default and in order to do that I had to configure my code to instruct it to read my cert file in the code. Problem is I don't know which it is as there are 269 files in the directory /etc/ssl/certs. I have googled for a couple hours hoping something would tell me where to look to check what file amazon generated for me that it specifically wants. Otherwise im shooting in the dark trying pems one at a time.

```
  secureProtocol: 'TLSv1_2_server_method',
  pfx: fs.readFileSync("/etc/ssl/certs/FILENAME.PEM")
}, app).listen(443);
```

Help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Your title talks about a *"certificate I created on AWS Certificates."*  Are you talking about an AWS Certificate Manager certificate that you attached to your load balancer?

Comment: i am referring to the pem needed to show i am https certified.

Answer (score 2):

Please refer EC2 instance details in AWS management console.

Steps:

1. Login to AWS management console and goto EC2 -> Instances.
2. Select the instance to which we need to connect and scroll the
   description which is present in bottom window which will have EC2
   instance details.
3. Check for "Key pair name" , this will be the key pair which needs
   to be used to securely connect to respective EC2 instance.

Comment: Thanks for the reply Ramya. But I was referring to the HTTPS certificate. Not to be confused with the PEM used to grant SSL access to the server.

Answer (score 1):

I assume that you got a certificate on Amazon ACM.

ACM Certificates can be used in,

- Elastic Load Balancing
- Amazon CloudFront
- Amazon API Gateway
- AWS Elastic Beanstalk
- AWS CloudFormation(for email validation only)

The certificate issued by ACM cannot be installed directly on an EC2 instance.

If you want to install an SSL certificate directly on your EC2 instance, you will need to obtain a SSL certificate through a third-party

Therefore, you cannot find any files related to the certificate issued by ACM inside your EC2 instance.

hope this helps.

Comment: If you want to use ACM issued certificate for your application, you can configure an elastic load balancer and configure SSL on the load balancer. After that you can configure your domain to point to the load balancer. hope this helps

Comment: does this answer help you.

Comment: sorry for the late response. I figured out that ultimately I didn't need to go though node to grab it that way but instead, had to reconfigure my code another way to accomplish the task. I was on wild goose chase after a red herring. Thanks though so much.